# How to bind textboxes in different user controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a MainWindow, and within it UserControl1 and UserControl2, which both contain a TextBox.

What is the best way to bind the Text property of these 2 textboxes.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DataBindTest1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:DataBindTest1">
    <StackPanel>
        <Controls:UserControl1/>
        <Controls:UserControl2/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataBindTest1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="uc1TextBox">ExampleText</TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl2.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataBindTest1.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
            <TextBox Name="uc2TextBox" /> <!--I want this to be bound to the Text property of uc1TextBox (which is in UserControl1)-->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Vijay

Comment: I changed UserControl2.xaml to this but it didnt work:   '<UserControl x:Class="DataBindTest1.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:DataBindTest1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="uc1TextBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=Controls:UserControl1.uc1TextBox,Path=Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may bind the `Text` property in both TextBoxes to a property of the same ViewModel object, which is set to the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` and inherited to the UserControls:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataBindTest1.UserControl1" ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="DataBindTest1.UserControl2" ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<Window x:Class="DataBindTest1.MainWindow" ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Controls:UserControl1/>
        <Controls:UserControl2/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The ViewModel class with the `Text` property that both UserControls bind to:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string someText;
    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return someText; }
        set
        {
            someText= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeText");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Clemens. That works for what I want to do. And has helped develop my understanding of WPF databinding. Thank you.  (Sorry I cant upvote your answer, as I only joined Stack Overflow today and dont have the min reputation level to do so).

Comment: Oh yes, thats how you do it. Thanks.